# Yourkit UI throwing "There's no application running at localhost with profiler agent configured to listen on port" exception

Tags: java, jboss, profiling, yourkit

I am trying to profile remote applications that are deployed within Jboss. So far I can connect to the remote server and see my applications, I am also able to connect to the applications. But when I click "Start CPU profiling", it takes really long time and most of the times results in the following exception:

```
There's no application running at localhost with profiler agent configured to listen on port 59462
or profiler agent is incompatible with current version of profiler
```

Although sometimes (rarely) it does start the profiling and give me the results what I want. But I am not able to understand this inconsistent behaviour and I also don't understand why does it give me an error saying "no application running on localhost ..." considering I am trying to profile a remote application.

Snippet from the machine where the UI is installed:

```
18.04-61 8341.339: com.yourkit.k.jm: LC@7fc6aab9{localhost:59131,pid=23651}: com.yourkit.b.bb: Bad stream from profiled application
Technical detail: EOF
   at com.yourkit.b.o.a(a:211)
   at com.yourkit.b.o.b(a:53)
   at com.yourkit.b.q.a(a:3385)
   at com.yourkit.b.q.updateTables(a:320)
   at com.yourkit.api.ControllerImpl$31.perform(a:12)
   at com.yourkit.api.ControllerImpl.makeRequest(a:18)
   at com.yourkit.api.ControllerImpl.makeRequest(a:534)
   at com.yourkit.api.ControllerImpl.updateDatabaseTables(a:200)
   at com.yourkit.k.jd.b(a:119)
   at com.yourkit.k.jd.b(a:286)
   at com.yourkit.k.jm.a(a:150)
   at com.yourkit.api.ControllerImpl$30.perform(a:3)
   at com.yourkit.api.ControllerImpl.makeRequest(a:163)
   at com.yourkit.api.ControllerImpl.makeRequest(a:534)
   at com.yourkit.api.ControllerImpl.runBatch(a:544)
   at com.yourkit.k.jm.run(a:150)

18.04-61 8341.339: com.yourkit.k.jm: LC@924ccd1{localhost:59570,pid=23851}: com.yourkit.b.bb: Bad stream from profiled application
Technical detail: EOF
   at com.yourkit.b.o.a(a:211)
   at com.yourkit.b.o.b(a:60)
   at com.yourkit.b.q.a(a:1275)
   at com.yourkit.b.q.updateTables(a:320)
   at com.yourkit.api.ControllerImpl$31.perform(a:12)
   at com.yourkit.api.ControllerImpl.makeRequest(a:18)
   at com.yourkit.api.ControllerImpl.makeRequest(a:534)
   at com.yourkit.api.ControllerImpl.updateDatabaseTables(a:200)
   at com.yourkit.k.jd.b(a:119)
   at com.yourkit.k.jd.b(a:286)
   at com.yourkit.k.jm.a(a:150)
   at com.yourkit.api.ControllerImpl$30.perform(a:3)
   at com.yourkit.api.ControllerImpl.makeRequest(a:163)
   at com.yourkit.api.ControllerImpl.makeRequest(a:534)
   at com.yourkit.api.ControllerImpl.runBatch(a:544)
   at com.yourkit.k.jm.run(a:150)

18.04-61 8341.339: com.yourkit.k.jm: LC@1fe95a4b{localhost:59991,pid=23983}: com.yourkit.b.bb: Bad stream from profiled application
Technical detail: EOF
   at com.yourkit.b.o.a(a:211)
   at com.yourkit.b.o.b(a:74)
   at com.yourkit.b.q.a(a:1854)
   at com.yourkit.b.q.updateTables(a:320)
   at com.yourkit.api.ControllerImpl$31.perform(a:12)
   at com.yourkit.api.ControllerImpl.makeRequest(a:18)
   at com.yourkit.api.ControllerImpl.makeRequest(a:534)
   at com.yourkit.api.ControllerImpl.updateDatabaseTables(a:200)
   at com.yourkit.k.jd.b(a:119)
   at com.yourkit.k.jd.b(a:286)
   at com.yourkit.k.jm.a(a:150)
   at com.yourkit.api.ControllerImpl$30.perform(a:3)
   at com.yourkit.api.ControllerImpl.makeRequest(a:163)
   at com.yourkit.api.ControllerImpl.makeRequest(a:534)
   at com.yourkit.api.ControllerImpl.runBatch(a:544)
   at com.yourkit.k.jm.run(a:150)

18.04-61 8344.342: com.yourkit.k.jm: LC@1fe95a4b{localhost:59991,pid=23983}: com.yourkit.util.bs: There's no application running at localhost with profiler agent configured to listen on port 59991
   at com.yourkit.api.ControllerImpl.transformException(a:273)
   at com.yourkit.api.ControllerImpl.makeRequest(a:293)
   at com.yourkit.api.ControllerImpl.makeRequest(a:534)
   at com.yourkit.api.ControllerImpl.runBatch(a:544)
   at com.yourkit.k.jm.run(a:150)

18.04-61 8346.665: com.yourkit.b.bh: LC@74c29709{localhost:60361,pid=23651}: created; local=false
18.04-61 8347.545: com.yourkit.b.q: snapshot_outer: starting: null
18.04-61 8347.545: com.yourkit.k.jm: LC@1fe95a4b{localhost:59991,pid=23983}: com.yourkit.util.bs: There's no application running at localhost with profiler agent configured to listen on port 59991
   at com.yourkit.api.ControllerImpl.transformException(a:273)
   at com.yourkit.api.ControllerImpl.makeRequest(a:293)
   at com.yourkit.api.ControllerImpl.makeRequest(a:534)
   at com.yourkit.api.ControllerImpl.runBatch(a:544)
   at com.yourkit.k.jm.run(a:150)

18.04-61 8347.545: com.yourkit.k.jm: LC@1fe95a4b{localhost:59991,pid=23983}: disconnected
18.04-61 8347.545: com.yourkit.b.q: controller telemetry limit: 3600
18.04-61 8347.545: com.yourkit.b.q: snapshot_outer: done in 0 sec: null
18.04-61 8379.660: com.yourkit.k.my: error: com.yourkit.util.bs: There's no application running at localhost with profiler agent configured to listen on port 60361
or profiler agent is incompatible with current version of profiler
   at com.yourkit.api.ControllerImpl.transformException(a:278)
   at com.yourkit.api.ControllerImpl.makeRequest(a:293)
   at com.yourkit.api.ControllerImpl.makeRequest(a:534)
   at com.yourkit.api.ControllerImpl.startCpuProfiling(a:154)
   at com.yourkit.k.kt.a(a:92)
   at com.yourkit.k.jo.b(a:60)
   at com.yourkit.k.d.al.a(a:183)
   at com.yourkit.k.dz.run(a:16)
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
   at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
   at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(SocketInputStream.java:116)
   at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:171)
   at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)
   at com.yourkit.b.bj.read(a:21)
   at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:246)
   at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:286)
   at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:345)
   at java.io.DataInputStream.readFully(DataInputStream.java:195)
   at java.io.DataInputStream.readLong(DataInputStream.java:416)
   at com.yourkit.runtime.Packet.readHeader(a:3)
   at com.yourkit.runtime.Packet.readHeader(a:51)
   at com.yourkit.runtime.Packet.readHeaderWithStandardResponse(a:17)
   at com.yourkit.api.ControllerImpl.readHeaderWithStandardResponse(a:10)
   at com.yourkit.api.ControllerImpl.access$100(a:558)
   at com.yourkit.api.ControllerImpl$3.perform(a:8)
   at com.yourkit.api.ControllerImpl.makeRequest(a:163)
   ... 6 more

18.04-61 9097.534: com.yourkit.k.my: error: com.yourkit.util.bs: There's no application running at localhost with profiler agent configured to listen on port 60361
or profiler agent is incompatible with current version of profiler
   at com.yourkit.api.ControllerImpl.transformException(a:278)
   at com.yourkit.api.ControllerImpl.makeRequest(a:293)
   at com.yourkit.api.ControllerImpl.makeRequest(a:534)
   at com.yourkit.api.ControllerImpl.startCpuProfiling(a:154)
   at com.yourkit.k.kt.a(a:92)
   at com.yourkit.k.jo.b(a:60)
   at com.yourkit.k.d.al.a(a:183)
   at com.yourkit.k.dz.run(a:16)
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
   at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
   at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(SocketInputStream.java:116)
   at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:171)
   at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)
   at com.yourkit.b.bj.read(a:21)
   at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:246)
   at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:286)
   at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:345)
   at java.io.DataInputStream.readFully(DataInputStream.java:195)
   at java.io.DataInputStream.readLong(DataInputStream.java:416)
   at com.yourkit.runtime.Packet.readHeader(a:3)
   at com.yourkit.runtime.Packet.readHeader(a:51)
   at com.yourkit.runtime.Packet.readHeaderWithStandardResponse(a:17)
   at com.yourkit.api.ControllerImpl.readHeaderWithStandardResponse(a:10)
   at com.yourkit.api.ControllerImpl.access$100(a:558)
   at com.yourkit.api.ControllerImpl$3.perform(a:8)
   at com.yourkit.api.ControllerImpl.makeRequest(a:163)
   ... 6 more

18.04-61 9191.727: com.yourkit.k.jm: LC@74c29709{localhost:60361,pid=23651}: com.yourkit.util.bs: There's no application running at localhost with profiler agent configured to listen on port 60361
or profiler agent is incompatible with current version of profiler
   at com.yourkit.api.ControllerImpl.transformException(a:278)
   at com.yourkit.api.ControllerImpl.makeRequest(a:293)
   at com.yourkit.api.ControllerImpl.makeRequest(a:534)
   at com.yourkit.api.ControllerImpl.getStatus(a:308)
   at com.yourkit.api.ControllerImpl.cacheStatuses(a:175)
   at com.yourkit.k.jd.b(a:130)
   at com.yourkit.k.jd.b(a:286)
   at com.yourkit.k.jm.a(a:150)
   at com.yourkit.api.ControllerImpl$30.perform(a:3)
   at com.yourkit.api.ControllerImpl.makeRequest(a:163)
   at com.yourkit.api.ControllerImpl.makeRequest(a:534)
   at com.yourkit.api.ControllerImpl.runBatch(a:544)
   at com.yourkit.k.jm.run(a:150)
Caused by: java.io.EOFException
   at java.io.DataInputStream.readFully(DataInputStream.java:197)
   at java.io.DataInputStream.readLong(DataInputStream.java:416)
   at com.yourkit.runtime.Packet.readHeader(a:3)
   at com.yourkit.runtime.Packet.readHeader(a:51)
   at com.yourkit.runtime.Packet.readHeaderWithStandardResponse(a:17)
   at com.yourkit.api.ControllerImpl.readHeaderWithStandardResponse(a:10)
   at com.yourkit.api.ControllerImpl.access$100(a:558)
   at com.yourkit.api.ControllerImpl$2.perform(a:5)
   at com.yourkit.api.ControllerImpl.makeRequest(a:18)
   ... 11 more

18.04-61 9268.954: com.yourkit.h.c.k: SSH: delPortForwarding error: Task java.util.concurrent.FutureTask@3ea383e2 rejected from java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor@60cb8835[Terminated, pool size = 0, active threads = 0, queued tasks = 0, completed tasks = 55]
18.04-61 9271.891: com.yourkit.h.a.e: 
  cmd: /home/dpagmk/software/jdk1.7.0_45/jre/bin/java -cp .yjp/2018.04-b61/lib/yourkit.jar -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Dyk.logger.stdErrOnly=true com.yourkit.Main -host-server
  request: getVmInfos
  exit code: -1
  stdout:
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007f509d520ac0, pid=16167, tid=139984557885184
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (7.0_45-b18) (build 1.7.0_45-b18)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (24.45-b08 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [libyjpagent.so+0x14cac0]  Options::containsSubstring(YStringImpl<char> const&)+0x0
#
# Failed to write core dump. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core dumping, try "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# /home/admin/hs_err_pid16167.log
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.sun.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#

18.04-61 9278.271: com.yourkit.b.bh: LC@3f153e3{localhost:61219,pid=23720}: created; local=false
18.04-61 9279.359: com.yourkit.b.q: snapshot_outer: starting: null
18.04-61 9279.359: com.yourkit.b.q: controller telemetry limit: 3600
18.04-61 9279.359: com.yourkit.b.q: snapshot_outer: done in 0 sec: null
18.04-61 9313.164: com.yourkit.k.my: error: com.yourkit.util.bs: There's no application running at localhost with profiler agent configured to listen on port 61219
or profiler agent is incompatible with current version of profiler
   at com.yourkit.api.ControllerImpl.transformException(a:278)
   at com.yourkit.api.ControllerImpl.makeRequest(a:293)
   at com.yourkit.api.ControllerImpl.makeRequest(a:534)
   at com.yourkit.api.ControllerImpl.startCpuProfiling(a:154)
   at com.yourkit.k.kt.a(a:92)
   at com.yourkit.k.jo.b(a:60)
   at com.yourkit.k.d.al.a(a:183)
   at com.yourkit.k.dz.run(a:16)
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
   at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
   at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(SocketInputStream.java:116)
   at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:171)
   at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)
   at com.yourkit.b.bj.read(a:21)
   at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:246)
   at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:286)
   at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:345)
   at java.io.DataInputStream.readFully(DataInputStream.java:195)
   at java.io.DataInputStream.readLong(DataInputStream.java:416)
   at com.yourkit.runtime.Packet.readHeader(a:3)
   at com.yourkit.runtime.Packet.readHeader(a:51)
   at com.yourkit.runtime.Packet.readHeaderWithStandardResponse(a:17)
   at com.yourkit.api.ControllerImpl.readHeaderWithStandardResponse(a:10)
   at com.yourkit.api.ControllerImpl.access$100(a:558)
   at com.yourkit.api.ControllerImpl$3.perform(a:8)
   at com.yourkit.api.ControllerImpl.makeRequest(a:163)
   ... 6 more
```

It would be great if someone can explain and guide in this matter.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So finally I was able to solve my problem with the help of Yourkit support team. Here is what they told me:

> Please try to increase socket timeouts of the profiler profiler UI by
>   specifying -Dyk.controller.connect.timeout.ms= (default is
>   5000 ms = 5 s) and -Dyk.controller.read.timeout.ms= (default
>   is 30000 ms = 30 s) in /.yjp/ui.ini
>
> For example, set
>
> -Dyk.controller.connect.timeout.ms=60000
>   -Dyk.controller.read.timeout.ms=60000

I hope it is helpful to others facing the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

I've just faced the same strange behavior. A day ago I manged to profile the app remotly but not today. I connect to the remote JVM through SSH and any settings has not been changed.

Comment: It is also inconsistent for me. Do you happen to know why does it refer to a specific port number in the exception? and which machine does it mean when it says "localhost"? Is it localhost for the agent or localhost for the UI application?